# What is the use of a max function in the bound of an integral?

Tags: calculus, probability

Regarding the following exercise I have two questions.

**Problem**: Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent identically distributed random variables, each with probability density function $f(x)=1 / x^2$ on  $1 \leq x \leq \infty$ and $0$ otherwise.
Find the joint probability density function of $U=X_1 X_2$ and $V=$ $X_1 / X_2$.

**Solution**: The joint PDF of $\left(X_1, X_2\right)$ is $f_{X_1,X_2}\left(x_1, x_2\right)=1 /\left(x_1^2 x_2^2\right)$ for $x_1 \geq 1$ and $x_2 \geq 1$, and $0$ otherwise. The inverse function is $X_1=\sqrt{U V}$ and $X_2=\sqrt{U / V}$. The Jacobian is then
$$
J=\left\|\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{V}{U}} & \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{U}{V}} \\
\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{U V}} & -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{U}{V^3}}
\end{array}\right\|=\frac{1}{2 V}.
$$
Hence, the joint PDF of $(U, V)$ is
$$
f_{U, V}(u, v)=f_{X_1,X_2}\left(\sqrt{u v}, \sqrt{u / v}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{2 v}=\frac{1}{2 u^2 v},
$$
for $u v \geq 1$ and $u / v \geq 1$, and $0$ otherwise. That is
$$
f_{U, V}(u, v)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\frac{1}{2 u^2 v}, & u \geq 1,1 / u \leq v \leq u \\
0, & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$

**My question** lies in determining the marginal PDF of $V$. I understand the general procedure of determining a marginal PDF. Namely, integrating the joint PDF of the 'other' variable(s) on the specified domain. However, I have difficulties with the latter. I will first give the solution:

$$
\begin{align}f_V(v)
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{U, V}(u, v) d u\\
&=\int_{\max (v, 1 / v)}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2 u^2 v} d u\\
&=\frac{1}{2 v} \frac{1}{\max (v, 1 / v)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \max \left(v^2, 1\right)}.
\end{align}$$

With algebra I can rewrite the given boundaries to
$u \geq \frac{1}{v}, u \geq v, u \geq 1 $. From here it is clear that I should take the maximum of the three option as the lower boundary. But when I plot $1 / u \leq v \leq u $, I only get one 'option'.

In the illustration, the defined area is in the first quadrant under the blue line and above the red line. The intersection of the two lines is at $u = 1$, with $u$ the horizontal axis and $v$ the vertical axis. [image]

It seems that I get two different answers with the two methods. It also seems like the plotting method is incomplete. My question: which method is correct, and why do I get two different answers?

Comment: $f_V(v)=\frac 1 2$ for $0<v<1$ and $\frac 1 {2v^{2}}$ for $1<v<\infty$.

Comment: I think I understand better, thanks